# Is it possible to detect a hdmi splitter between graphic card and monitor?

Tags: windows, splitter, hdmi

I do not know where I should ask this question.
Is there any possibility to detect a hdmi splitter between graphic card and monitor on a Windows 10 system?

I mean a software solution.
I am sitting in front of the system so I can see there is a splitter :).

Comment: No. How would Windows be able to tell you have a splitter downline from the computer?

Comment: mabye over singal strength or what ever

Comment: I don't think you understand what HDMI is... It's not a continual stream of data flowing back and forth. What *signal* would you expect to monitor?

Comment: That is why I asked. I assumed there is a communication in both directions possible and maybe there is a method to detect a splitter. It is just a academic interest. There is no specific signal just the normal desktop screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the electrical spec for the various cable types would allow the card to detect the split.  Even if it could, I don't think Windows has an API to report it.

Windows has the "[Protected Media Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Media_Path)" which makes it hard to programmatically snoop on DRM-encumbered content while it's on the PC.

The PMP is going to let the full-res DRM'ed content go out over the cable only if the [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) handshake works, allowing the PC to confirm that the display device at the other end is "authorized."  Assuming the HDCP handshake works over the split cable, the data seen by the "third end" of your split cable would still be encrypted.

Whether the handshake leaks enough information to decrypt the data, I don't know.

If the content is not DRM'ed, then I don't think Windows would care if there's a splitter, so, again, I don't think it has an API to detect this.